# How to calculate the center of a closed higher degree algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a closed algebraic planar curve in a general position. From a picture it is obvious that the curve has a center (so there are two mutually perpendicular lines, and the curve is symmetric with respect to them). However, we know only the equation $F(x,y)=0$ and nothing more.
How to calculate the center if the degree of $F$ is greater than two? (Of course, for conic sections it is well known.) 
Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: For real quartics [say this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitangents_of_a_quartic) or $(x^2+y^2)^2+2x^4+5x^3y+x^2y^2+6x y^2+3y^4-1=0$, do you want the "center" of each [oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_plane_curve)?

Comment: Does this quartics perhaps possess symmetries about which I write?

Comment: And the Trott curve from the link has only one center in this sense. Yes, if the Troot curve is shifted and rotated, i.e. in a general position, and given only by its equation, then a determination of the center is an example of my problem.